# Acentos não estão sendo removidos nos slugs

Tags: bug, status-intencional, localização

Normalmente os *slugs* substituem alguns caracteres especiais. Por exemplo: `ã` por `a` e `ç` por `c`. Porém, aqui no Stack isso não está acontecendo:

```
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540/qual-resposta-marcar-como-aceita-se-as-duas-est%C3%A3o-corretas
```

Note que o `ã` por subsituído por `%C3%A3`, quando o ideal seria `a`, por motivos de legibilidade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algum tempo atrás, caracteres especiais eram *removidos* dos slugs, mas isso foi alterado alguns dias atrás. Agora eles são aceitos e utilizados de forma normal na url, de acordo com o Marc [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214531/convert-diacritics-to-normal-letters-in-the-profile-link/233832#233832).

No seu caso, `%C3%A3` é a representação válida de `ã` numa URL, mas alguns navegadores não dão suporte. No meu (Opera 22, Windows 8.1) o slug é resolvido corretamente:

[image: url contendo caracteres especiais]

Se você quiser evitar os conjuntos esquisitos de caracteres na hora de enviar o link para alguém, use o botão "Compartilhar" logo abaixo do post, que vai te dar a URL curta, sem o slug.

Comment: Entendi. É que aqui os caracteres também são resolvidos na barra de URL, mas não quando você copia e cola em algum outro lugar. Usarei o botão Compartilhar

Comment: Ou copie só até a barra antes do slug, se estiver mais "à mão" na hora.